# Visual Studio 2010 create a table like excel for input data

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am using **Visual Studio Express**,  and I am tryng to add a form to my Windows application with rows and columns, but I cannot find any WindowsForm like a table or cells design.

I tried to create diferrents Textbox, but I need around two columns and 10 rows with a title and its not practical to add many textboxes.

[image]

Comment: It's called a DataGridView

Comment: Thanks! can you Write your response like an answer. to accept your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the DataGridView control:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0ywh3cz.aspx